# CFA, 1 latent variable, 3 observed, saturated, how to continue?

Tags: confirmatory-factor, lavaan

For a survey on work satisfaction and health containing multiple constructs (for stress, intrinsic motivation, anxiety, quality of life), I need to confirm the unidimensionality of each construct. Constructs are measured using 3 indicators. Of course, each of my CFA is then saturated (0 df). How can I continue? My constructs are not theoretically related, so does it make sense to add them to 1 CFA model? Or can I add additional constraints? Or do i just interpret the factor loadings and do not report the model fit?

```
ex.model <- '=~ x1 + x2 + x3'
fit <- cfa(ex.model, data=dataset,ordered=c("x1","x2","x3"))
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand your Lavaan model. What's on the LHS of the formula, one of the 4 constucts? Also, CFA is not the only way to assess unidimensionality. Why do you need CFA in this case?